# Replace a line with sed but keeping original line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line, sed

I have a line like:

```
param1='123'
```

I would like the following:

```
param1='123'
param2=123
```

Where `123` can be any value.

I can get `param2` using:

```
sed -i "s/param1=\([0-9]\+\)/param2='\1'/g" '{}' \;
```

But then I will lose `param1`.

I can also append line `param2` using:

```
sed -i "param1='\([0-9]\+\)';/a \param2=\1;"
```

But the pattern isn't recognised and I end up with `param2=1`

Is there a way to combine these two commands or another way of working this?

Comment: it's generally better to wrap `sed` inline scripts in single-quotes. Then you don't have to worry if there is any  interaction with the shell's processing of cmd lines. only use dbl-quotes for sed inline scripts if you need to pass in a shell variable and have it expanded (again, as a general, but not hard-and-fast rule). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you shelter. I used double quotes because I didn't want the single quotes to interfere with the single quotes surrounding 123. Perhaps I can escape with \'123\'

Comment: sorry, I missed that about your pattern. I don't think that `'...\'123\'...'` will work. But you can adjoin various quoting methods, i.e. `'...'"'123'"'....'` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Giving a extension to the `-i` flag create a backup so `foo.ini` will be updated and the original unmodified version will be found `foo.ini.bak`:

```
$ find . -name '*ini' -exec sed -ri.bak 's/param1=.([0-9]+)./&\nparam2=\1/' {} \;
```

In the `sed` command the `g` flag is probably redundant as in Unix configuration files a single option is set on a single line. The command replaces `param1=123` with `param1=123\nparam2=123` as `&` represents the whole match and the value `123` is caught in the first capture group.

```
&        # Whole match
\n       # Newline character
param2=  # Literal string
\1       # First capture group
```

So basically the line is duplicated but option is changed and the value stays the same.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try it in a second. Please note I did not mean the single quotes to be there in param2, does that change your answer? i've edited the question

Comment: @user1792403 my mistake, I thought it was an omission on your part. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: this seems a bit more complicated and i'm pretty new to sed. but +1 as it looks exciting and when i understand things better i'll come back to look at this

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "p;s/1='\([^']*\)'.*/2=\1/" file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
sed -r "s/(param1='([^']*)')/\1\nparam2=\2/" filename
```

(Add the `-i` option for in-place edit.)

Comment: This works with `-r` option, but i get this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 35: invalid reference \2 on \`s' command's RHS` if i change `-r` to `-i` or `-e`

Answer (score -1):

`sed -i "s/\(param1='\([0-9]\+\)'\)/\1\nparam2=\2/g"`

seems to work.

Similar to what devnull answered, but works without the -r (Need to add backslash before parenthesis when not using extended regexp).